# How to fix VBA code that follows hyperlink in a relative cell if there and returns message box if there is no hyperlink?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set up contextual help in an excel spreadsheet where the user clicks into the cell they need help, they click a help button and the hyperlink that is relevant to that cell is followed (I have replicated the layout within the worksheet and within that layout, where there is help, there is a hyperlink). The code works except not all cells have help which leads to a debug message. I need a solution to account for where there is no hyperlink (message box?).

I have tried using on error resume next - the code works where there is a hyperlink but when there isn't I get Run-Time Error 9 Subscript out of range.

This is the full code:

```
Sub HELP()
'
' HELP Macro
'

'On Error Resume Next
 ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=31
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 39).Range("A1").Select
 Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
 If Error <> "" Then MsgBox ("Nowhere to go, Nothing to see")
 ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
 ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, -39).Range("A1").Select
 End Sub
```

Upon debugging the line:

```
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True"
```

Is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful to anyone else; I solved it;

```
Sub HELP()
'
' HELP Macro
'
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 39).Range("A1").Select
If ActiveCell <> "" Then
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -39).Range("A1").Select
Else
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -39).Range("A1").Select
MsgBox "No associated help"
End If
End Sub
```